# Clicking Load More Leads leads to error stating that element is no longer visible

Tags: java, selenium

I have a Search Screen where after I enter the search criteria and search a Load More button will display if there are more than 30 records. The problem is it clicks the Load more button but leads to stale element Exception

The scenario is I need to click till the Load More button becomes disabled.

Below is my code any inputs

List rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody[@role='rowgroup']/tr"));
int rowcount = rows.size();

```
        String loadmoreXpath = AppXPathsConstants.buttonXpath_replace.replace("XXXX","Load More");
    
        if(driver.findElements(By.xpath(loadmoreXpath)).size()!= 0) 
        {
            
        WebElement loadmoreElem = DriverUtil.getFluentWaitElementByXPath(loadmoreXpath,20, driver);
    
        do
        {
            PageUtil.scrolltoBottom(driver);
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'mat-button-wrapper') and contains(normalize-space(),'Load More')]")));
            loadmoreElem.click();
            DriverUtil.waitTime(6000);
            WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
             w.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(loadmoreXpath)));
        }

        while(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'mat-button-wrapper') and contains(normalize-space(),'Load More')]")).size()>0);
        }
```

StackTrace:
And on running the code i get the below issue:
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to no longer be visible: By.xpath: //span[contains(@class,'mat-button-wrapper') and contains(normalize-space(),'Load More')] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: @pmadhu - sorry cannot do that

Comment: Atleast share the complete error message.

Comment: @pmadhu - added stack trace

Comment: `WebElement loadmoreElems` is defined outside the loop, redefine it inside loop again and try.

Comment: @pmadhu - that wont make a difference tried and still the same

Answer (score 0):

I think its because, you are defining `loadmoreElems` (within the loop) after you perform the click operation. So it click on the `Load More` button one time because you have defined `loadmoreElems` outside the loop. After the 1st click you are not defining it before click operation and the previously defined `loadmoreElems` is no longer valid.

Define it before that and try:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'mat-button-wrapper') and contains(normalize-space(),'Load More')]")));
loadmoreElems = DriverUtil.getFluentWaitElementByXPath(loadmoreXpath,20, driver);
loadmoreElems.click();
if(!loadmoreElem.isDisplayed())...
```

Comment: that does not solve the problem even if it is defined inside or outside that is  not the issue -if any other inputs pls let me know - @pmadhu

Comment: Did it click on the `Load more` only once like before. Or did it click twice?

Comment: once only it clicked

Comment: @Sandy - Have faced a similar kind of situation. Check this code once, it might help you.[GoggleReviews-ShowMore](https://pastebin.com/aRLvjNH1)